# API request search issue - how do I search through all pages

Tags: python, get

I am trying to search through multiple pages through an API GET request but I am unsure how to search passed the first page of results.

The first GET request will download the first page of results but to get to the next page you need to GET the new URL which is listed at the bottom of the first page.

```
def getaccount_data():
    view_code = input("Enter Account: ")
    global token
    header = {"X-Fid-Identity": token}
    url = BASE_URL + '/data/v1/entity/account'
    accountdata = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify = False)
    newaccountdata = accountdata.json()
        
    for data in newaccountdata ['results']:
        if (data['fields']['view_code']) == view_code:
            print("Account is set up")
            
    else:
        url =(newaccountdata['moreUri'])
        print(url)     
      
getaccount_data()
```

Is there anyway to search all the pages by updating the url to get to the next page?

Comment: Put it all in a loop?

Comment: I need to update the url each time the loop restarts though?